# json callback flickr api

Tags: json, api, callback, flickr

I have checked my url is working fine but unable to get the call to work. Does anyone see what might be wrong here? thanks.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&
    api_key=e4a2bd36f274dc8cbec976f87d31ac91&text=dandy&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data)
    {
       $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
       $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images")
      .wrap("<a href='" + item.link + "'></a>");
     });
       $('#images').cycle({
         fx: 'fade',
         speed: 'fast',
         timeout: 0,
         next: '#next',
         prev: '#prev'
      });
    });
 });
```

I have also tried with the authorization token and api signature:
   http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=e4a2bd36f274dc8cbec976f87d31ac91&text=dandy&format=json&auth_token=72157629614542470-3c6e999c34de2fef&api_sig=1ba75b356a910f6b2872f356153075bf

Getting this error in firebug:
JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Comment: When you try this in Chrome or Firebug, what does the net panel say as answer? I'd suggest you validate the returned JSON at jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

Your script appears to be expecting an RSS Feed like structure to the items in it (data.item, item.media.m etc). This is not how the JSON data is formatted that is returned from the Flickr API.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&  api_key=3a68f22971d8d66b521b362c312c175c&text=dandy&extras=url_m&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data)
    {
       $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
       $("<img/>").attr("src", item.url_m).appendTo("#images")
      .wrap("<a href='" + item.url_m + "'></a>");
    });
    $('#images').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 'fast',
        timeout: 0,
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#prev'
    });
    });
});​
```

Note the inclusion of "extras=url_m" in the url, and the change to data.photos.photo and item.url_m.